# AngularJS Service with multiple, depending queries

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, service, factory

I'm trying to create an AngularJS service, which returns data based on several HTTP requests. But i seem to just not get it to work.

The REST call works as follow:

- get /index which returns an array of urls
- call each of the url's, and add the result to an array

I expect that at the end of the call of the service function, that i receive a data structure containing all the data from the url's.

My current, somewhat working code uses callbacks, but even though it works in one controller, it does not in another. I want to correctly use promises, but i'm already confused with success vs then.

My service:

```
        // Get a image
         obj.getByUrl = function (imageUrl, callback) {
                 $http.get('https://localhost:9000' + imageUrl).success(function (data) {
                     callback(data);
                 });
         }

            // Get all images
            obj.getAll = function(callback) {
                    $http.get('https://localhost:9000/1.0/images').success(function (data) {

                      if (data.status != "Success") {
                        console.log("Err");
                      }

                      var images = [];
                      for(var n=0; n < data.metadata.length; n++) {
                        var c = data.metadata[n];

                        obj.getByUrl(c, function(data2) {
                          images.push(data2.metadata);
                        });

                      }
                      callback(images);
                    });
                }
```

i'd like to use the service in a controller resolve like this:

```
resolve : {
  images: function(ImagesServices, $route) {
    return ImagesServices.getState($route.current.params.containerName)
},
```

I came as far as this, but it does only return the data of the index call, not the aggregated data:

```
                obj.getAll3 = function() {
              var images = [];
              var promises = [];

              //var httpPromise = $http.get('https://localhost:9000/1.0/images');
              var httpPromise = $http({
                url: 'https://localhost:9000/1.0/images',
                method: 'GET',
              });

              return httpPromise.success(function(data) {
                  var data2 = data.metadata[0];
                  // angular.forEach(data.metadata, function(data2) {
                  console.log("D11: " + JSON.stringify(data2));

                  //var inPromise = $http.get('https://localhost:9000' + data2)
                  var inPromise = $http({
                    url: 'https://localhost:9000' + data2,
                    method: 'GET',
                  })
                  .success(function (data2) {
                    console.log("D2: " + JSON.stringify(data2));
                    images.push(data2);
                  });

                  promises.push(inPromise);
                  // });

                  return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                    return images;
                  });
              });
          }
```

Maybe someone can point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical case where chaining promises, and using $q.all(), is adequate:

```
/**
 * returns a promise of array of images
 */
obj.getAll = function() {
    // start by executing the first request
    return $http.get('https://localhost:9000/1.0/images').then(function(response) {

        // transform the response into a promise of images

        // if that's not possible, return a rejected promise
        if (data.status != "Success") {
            return $q.reject("Error");
        }

        // otherwise, transform the metadata array into
        // an array of promises of image
        var promises = data.metadata.map(function(imageUrl) {
            return $http.get('https://localhost:9000' + imageUrl).then(function(resp) {
                return resp.data;
            });
        });

        // and transform this array of promises into a promise
        // of array of images
        return $q.all(promises);
    });
}
```

This avoid the callback antipattern, and uses chaining. It's a bit long to explain here, but I wrote a blog post that should, hopefully, make the above code clear: http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. Simple, elegant and clean code, works perfect. Thx!

One of the problems I encountered when I tried to develop my own solution was that I didnt know that .success() works in parallel, whereas .then() is serial.

Comment: It isn't parallel. But it doesn't allow chaining promises. It's deprecated anyway, and shouldn't be used anymore.